# An orthogonal matrix that fails to be an isometry?

Tags: linear-algebra

An isometry is defined to be a transformation $h\colon \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $\|h(x) - h(y) \|= \| x- y\|$. In other words, an isometry preserves euclidean distances.

A theorem in my textbook (Analysis on Manifolds) states that if $h(0) = 0$,  where $h\colon \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$, then

1) $h$ is an isometry iff it preserves dot products: $\langle h(x), h(y)\rangle$ = $\langle x,y\rangle.$

2) $h$ is an isometry iff it is an orthogonal transformation: $h(x) = A \cdot x$ where $A$ is an orthonormal matrix.

Is there an instance of a map $h$ that preserves dot products and is an orthogonal transformation yet $h(0) \not = 0$, meaning that $h$ is not an isometry?

Comment: Well, (2) makes it clear that the answer is no...

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, I thought so as well. Perhaps the theorem is superfluous then?

Comment: Essentially you need for the columns to be orthogonal and to have norm $1$.

Comment: Your second paragraph says "if $h(x)=0$". Should it have said "if $h(0)=0$"?

Comment: Maybe a translation?

Comment: Isometries are not required to map $0$ to $0$. For example, every translation is an isometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A translation by a non-zero vector is an isometry that
does not preserve dot products and is not of the form
$h(x) = Ax$ where $A$ is orthonormal.
Therefore, if we leave out the condition $h(0)=0,$
the theorem is false.

*With* the condition $h(0)=0,$ however, we restrict ourselves to
linear transformations, which excludes non-zero translations.
Among the linear transformations, all isometries preserve the dot product
and are of the form $h(x) = Ax$ where $A$ is orthonormal.
That is what the theorem asserts.